# Why is LSTM so ineffective at this ridiculously simple sequence?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to predict the the sequence  $(0.1, 0.05, …, 1.1)$ from the sequence $(0, 0.05, 0.1, …, 1)$. I thought this would be the only item in a toy dataset.

Now I implemented a long-short term memory [LSTM](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html) model in PyTorch and I can't figure out why it trains so badly.

With learning rate $10^{-3}$ and $10^3$ iterations *on this single data point* it fails to converge effectively. Results are bad.

With learning rate $10^{-4}$ and $10^4$ loss decreases more, and results are slightly better

Here is the code:

```
import torch import numpy as np

lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size=1, hidden_size=100, num_layers=1, batch_first=True).to(torch.double)
linear = torch.nn.Linear(100,1).to(torch.double)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
params = list(lstm.parameters()) + list(linear.parameters())
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params, 1e-3)

L = 21

x = torch.tensor(np.arange(L)/20, dtype=torch.double).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(2)
y = torch.tensor(np.arange(2,L+2)/20,  dtype=torch.double)

for j in range(1000):
    hidden = (torch.zeros((1,1,100), dtype=torch.double), torch.zeros((1,1,100), dtype=torch.double))
    x = x
    y = y
    output, hidden = lstm(x, hidden)
    loss = 0.0
    for i in range(L):
        o = linear(output[:,i,:].squeeze())
        loss += criterion(o, y.squeeze()[i])
    print(loss)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

out_seq = torch.empty((L)) for i in range(L):
    o = linear(output[:,i,:].squeeze())
    out_seq[i] = o
     print("output (expected): ", y) print("output:", out_seq)
```

It seems unreasonable to me that it requires to spend so much time on a single data sequence to figure out it has just to add 0.1 to each element. So I'd appreciate any insight on how to improve that.

Comment: I think the target sequence is supposed to be $(0.1,0.15,…,1.1)$ instead of $(0.1,0.05,…,1.1)$.

Comment: it doesn't even look like a sequential problem. How does knowledge about previous element in the sequence will effect prediction for the next element? Each element of the sequence can be trained independently from one another

Answer (score 2):

You have bug in the code. It looks like torch accumulates gradients and before making backpropagation you need to clean them (set to zero)

```
optimizer.zero_grad()  # add this line
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

I added this fix in your code and I get progress during the training. I got loss equal to `0.0005` after `1000` iterations with step `1e-3`.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48009142/2759088) from the stackoverflow. You can also check [this RNN tutorial](https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/recurrent_neural_network/main.py) on github

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the network should learn to entirely by-pass the LSTM cell(s), ie., close their output gate(s) forever. Adding 0.1 to the input needs only a bias weight (that is, a constant) added to the input. So, you don't even need a hidden layer at all. Some of the earlier LSTM work improved results dramatically by choosing the "right" bias weights for the LSTM gates. After all, you have a large network with many degrees-of-freedom and only few data points, so it may be tricky for the network to converge to that solution from your starting values.